# Adding an xmlns Attribute to a Start Element VB.Net

Tags: xml, vb.net

I'm building a VB.net console application that reads SQL and builds XML.  I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and .Net Framework 4.5.  My code is as follows:

```
Private _namespaceDefault as String = ""AAIS_Homeowners_Premium""

Dim writer As XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(policyDir & "\Policy.xml", settings)
writer.WriteStartDocument()
writer.WriteStartElement("ROOT")
writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "", Nothing, _namespaceDefault)
```

I've also tried this:

```
writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", _namespaceDefault)
```

When I run the program I get the following error:  "The prefix '' cannot be redefined from '' to 'AAIS_Homeowners_Premium' within the same start element tag.".  The xmlns value is not a URL but rather it's the name of the Schema file for validation.

How do I add the xmlns Attribute value to the Start Element?  The XML should look like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ROOT xmlns="AAIS_Homeowners_Premium">
    <Company>12345</Company>
    <LOB>ABCDEFG</LOB>
    <Policies>
        <Policy>
            <PolicyNumber>6789</PolicyNumber>
            <Date>01/24/2018</Date>
        </Policy>
        <Policy>
            <PolicyNumber>2345</PolicyNumber>
            <Date>03/17/2018</Date>
        </Policy>
    </Policies>
</ROOT>
```

Thank you.

Comment: dhead61 if you look at my answer it gives exactly what you want.

Comment: you keep editing your post. please stop as the answers cannot reflect what you want and you will need to figure it out with what is given. Thanks.

Comment: You might find it a little easier to work with XML literals and XElement / XDocument than building up the XML in code.  You can directly insert a value from code using `<%=` and `%>` e.g. `<Guid><%= Guid.NewGuid().ToString("D") %></Guid>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you do it using your code (although, both are helpful):

```
        Dim _namespaceDefault As String = "AAIS_Homeowners_Premium"

        Dim writer As Xml.XmlWriter = Xml.XmlWriter.Create("Policy.xml", settings)
        writer.WriteStartDocument()
        writer.WriteStartElement("ROOT", _namespaceDefault)
        writer.WriteElementString("Company", "12345")
        writer.WriteElementString("LOB", "ABCDEFG")
        writer.WriteStartElement("Policies")
        writer.WriteStartElement("Policy")
        writer.WriteElementString("PolicyNumber", "6789")
        writer.WriteElementString("Date", "01/24/2018")
        writer.WriteEndElement()  'Policy
        writer.WriteStartElement("Policy")
        writer.WriteElementString("PolicyNumber", "2345")
        writer.WriteElementString("Date", "03/17/2018")
        writer.WriteEndElement()  'Policy
        writer.WriteEndElement()  'Policies
        writer.WriteEndElement()  'ROOT
        writer.WriteEndDocument()

        writer.Close()

        writer = Nothing
```

and the output is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ROOT xmlns="AAIS_Homeowners_Premium">
      <Company>12345</Company>
      <LOB>ABCDEFG</LOB>
      <Policies>
        <Policy>
          <PolicyNumber>6789</PolicyNumber>
          <Date>01/24/2018</Date>
        </Policy>
        <Policy>
          <PolicyNumber>2345</PolicyNumber>
          <Date>03/17/2018</Date>
        </Policy>
      </Policies>
    </ROOT>
```

Comment: Did you check this post answer? it is using your coding methodology.

Comment: Thanks to both of you.  This is what I was looking for.  Although I did make a working version using the code from IAmNerd2000.  Now I have 2 copies for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code and output. should be what you are looking for:

Code:

```
        Dim _namespaceDefault As String = "AAIS_Homeowners_Premium"

        Dim doc As System.Xml.XmlDocument
        Dim elm As System.Xml.XmlNode
        Dim elmSub As System.Xml.XmlNode
        Dim elmMain As Xml.XmlNode

        doc = New Xml.XmlDocument

        elmMain = doc.CreateElement("ROOT")
        elmSub = elmMain.Attributes.Append(doc.CreateAttribute("xmlns"))
        elmSub.Value = _namespaceDefault

        elm = elmMain.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("FirstNode"))
        elm.InnerText = "12345"

        elm = elmMain.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("SecondNode"))
        elm.InnerText = "ABCDEFG"

        doc.AppendChild(doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", "no"))
        doc.AppendChild(elmMain)
        doc.Save("Policy.xml")
```

and the result:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
    <ROOT xmlns="AAIS_Homeowners_Premium">
      <FirstNode>12345</FirstNode>
      <SecondNode>ABCDEFG</SecondNode>
    </ROOT>
```

Comment: Will make a version using your approach.  Thanks.